# Update GNU-Make on Centos 7

Tags: centos, make

Is there a simple way to install a new version of GNU make on centos 7?
similar to the *devtoolset-8*.

Or is there only the *manual* way (download the tar)

Answer (score 0):

[CentOS 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS)
has since since 2020-08-06 passed from "Full updates" to "Maintenance updates".

This is
[defined](https://www.openlogic.com/blog/centos-8-eol) as:

> **Maintenance Updates**
>
> Following the “Full Updates” phase, the “Maintenance Updates” phase
> provided only security errata critical bug fixes for the version. This
> phase would last for around 4 years, after which the version would
> enter end of life.

As the update to the latest GNU make is not counted as a
"critical bug fix", you won't find the latest version in the repository.

You won't find official releases, but you might be able to find privately
compiled versions on the internet.

Comment: I'm aware that it is not on the "official" repository, but there is something like the devtoolset-8 which is a new version of the GCC which is also not critical..  But then I will try to do a manual install